# Remove all rows of a Dataframe in which at least one contains a specific id

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe with user statuses:

```
id  name      email          status_id  
23  Alex      a@a.com        1
23  Alex      a@a.com        2
23  Alex      a@a.com        3
25  Bill      b@b.com        2
25  Bill      b@b.com        3
28  Claire    c@c.com        3
29  David     d@d.com        1
29  David     d@d.com        2
```

I want to remove from the dataframe all users that has at least one row in which the status_id is equal to 1, in this case, the expected dataframe is:

```
id  name      email          status_id  
25  Bill      b@b.com        2
25  Bill      b@b.com        3
28  Claire    c@c.com        3
```

It would also be even better if I could get only the users without repetition, so the final dataframe would be:

```
id  name      email 
25  Bill      b@b.com
28  Claire    c@c.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.loc[~df.id.isin(df.id.loc[df.status_id==1])]
Out[504]: 
   id    name    email  status_id
3  25    Bill  b@b.com          2
4  25    Bill  b@b.com          3
5  28  Claire  c@c.com          3
```

Remove dup

```
df.loc[~df.id.isin(df.id.loc[df.status_id==1])].drop_duplicates('name')
Out[505]: 
   id    name    email  status_id
3  25    Bill  b@b.com          2
5  28  Claire  c@c.com          3
```

Comment: `df.groupby('id').filter(lambda L: L.status_id.ne(1).all())` is probably also an option....

Comment: Also maybe worth converting series to set for your comparison?